# Patent an item i have been selling

Tags: patentability

I came up with an idea several years ago and developed it to the stage of production and sales. I would now like to patent it due to the fact another competitor has started manufacturing it  and selling it too. I read somewhere that you cannot patent an item you have already sold and continue selling

Just wording if thats correct and if so is there another avenue I can explore

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the US you have a year grace period after your invention is made public, published, sold etc. to file for a patent it.

In most of the world you don’t get that but need to file before e posing the invention.

If you have established a trademark that can help but trademarks are off topic here.

Comment: So I totally messed up by not patenting it within the grace period

Comment: @Oden Yes, you can't obtain a patent. That said, it is possible there are reasons your invention might not have been patentable so don't beat yourself up.

Comment: If you could innovate a "next generation" version that was novel, kept its market, and was non-obvious to a P.H.O.S.I.T.A. , then you could patent that.  You could even put down a provisional patent for it while you work with a capable patent attorney to make sure it holds good water.

Comment: @EngrStudent Obligatory - “no such thing as a provisional *patent* only provisional patent *application*.”

Comment: @GeorgeWhite - you are ABSOLUTELY right.  sorry about that.